# Errors trying to install JCL in Delphi Alexandria

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I am attempting to install the JCL library into Delphi RAD Studio 11. Git placed the jcl tree in my Users directory (say C:\Users\xxx); I followed instructions and made sure I updated the modules, etc.

I then attempted to execute the install.bat file, located in the C:\Users\xxx\jcl\jcl directory. When I did that I got a message to the effect that my version of RAD Studio/Delphi does not support command line compiling. That's fine, I simply opened the JDIInstaller.bdsproj (located in the C:\Users\xxx\jcl\jcl\installer folder) with RAD Studio and built it, successfully.

I then tried running the project from within RAD Studio, but I couldn't, I got an error message telling me to shut down all running instances of Delphi. Instead, I ran the EXE file directly from the C:\Users\xxx\jcl\jcl\bin folder; it ran to completion and said the installation finished. So far, so good. I should note that the JCL installer set the BPL path to C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Bpl and the DCP path to C:\Users\xxx\jcl\jcl\lib\d28\win32.

The issue is this: When I then go to open RAD Studio, I get a number of messages like below. The text of the error message is:

> Can't load package C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Bpl\JclBaseExpert280.bpl.
> The specified module could not be found.
> Do you want to attempt to load this package the next time a package is loaded?

This dialog is repeated an additional six times (i.e. there are a total of seven messages). The file names are as follows (they all end with "Expert280.bpl", so I'm just giving the beginning part): Debug, FavoriteFolders, ProjectAnalysis, Repository, JCLSIMDView, JCLStackTraceViewer.

If I open Components->Install Packages in the RAD Studio IDE, the seven files appear in the Design Packages list, but unchecked. They all appear as "File C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Bpl" followed by the specific file name.

I checked, and the files exist in that location, but I know from my research that the message can be misleading; i.e., the message is returned by Windows which may be looking for a support file.

I don't know where to go from here.

I should note that previously I attempted to install JCL/JVCL into RAD Studio 2010 and initially got the same error message, but solved it by using a more recent version of JCL. However, there IS no more recent version of JCL that I can find.

Of course, it may be this cannot be done; i.e. install JCL/JVCL into Alexandria. Any information whether this is the case and, if not, what I might try would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add - trying to use Jedi with Alexandria and windows 10.  With Sydney I used Getit and it worked beautifully.  Alexandria hasnt got it listed which means back to the old manual method.  Removed everything (I think) from the previous RAD - installed the latest JCL (daily download) - at least it tells me all was installed. Tried to compile JVCL install project but got the 7 BPL files missing errors and it wont compile.  I use JV extensively so its a bit sad that installation is so naff.  Any help would be truly appreciated as am incredibly ancient and this is my hobby.

Comment: I am having similar issues (I'm using the CE version of 11.3). The 10.4 GETIT install was simple. I've wasted a lot of time trying to get this version installed. I'm getting the message initially that this version does not support command line compiling. I've tried to build individually and manually with some success, but then got messages that the compiler versions were different between JCL and JVCL components. Now uninstall everything and start again.

Answer (score 0):

The RAD install this time is into a folder marked 22.0 as against last times 21.0.  Before trying to install JCL and JVCL I renamed all folders 21xx to kill the links  (in Documents\embarcadero\studio  C:\users\public\documents\embarcadero\studio  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio).  Also did the same in Registry.  When I tried to install again it all worked..  Best of luck